# Making R Shiny remember the inputs and outputs for app having multi tab panel

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I currently have 2 tabPanel() in a Shiny app. The app lets the user upload an excel file. After the upload, the UI elements are generated, in the form of selectizeInput() where the user can select x and y variables. The output is a stacked plotly() graph of  one x variable and multiple y variables
I have two tab Panels in the app, In the first tabPanel, I select sheet1 of the excel file and their corresponding x and y variables. Similarly, I choose sheet 2 for the second tabPanel and their x and y,

The issue I am having here is I want Shiny to remember the inputs of the 1st tabPanel() after switching to the second tabPanel() and vice versa. Currently, the app refreshes to default state when the user switches between the tab panels. It remembers which sheet is selected in the tabs , but not the x and y variables, Here is a working sample code. I have also attached the excel file for reference - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QYqg0b-_YK7eUhR78usiM4NspZoj5Rfk/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100116750636203353695&rtpof=true&sd=true

How do I make this work?

```
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

lib <- c("DT","plotly","shiny","data.table", "readr", "openxlsx", "readxl", "tidyverse")

lapply(lib, require, character.only = TRUE)

plotly_stacked <- function(df, x_colName, cols){
  
  
  DF <- df[, cols] %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value, -x_colName ) %>%
    transform(id = as.integer(factor(variable)))
  
  DF$variable<- factor( DF$variable, levels = unique( DF$variable))
  names(DF) <- gsub("\\.", " ", names(DF))
  
  p <- plot_ly(data = DF, x = ~Time , y = ~value, color = ~variable, colors = "Dark2",
               yaxis = ~paste0( "y",sort(id, decreasing = F))
  ) %>%
    
    add_lines() %>%
    layout( 
      legend = list(orientation = "h",   # show entries horizontally
                    xanchor = "center",  # use center of legend as anchor
                    x = 0.5)) %>% 
    plotly::subplot(nrows = length(unique(DF$variable)), shareX = TRUE) 
  
  return(p)
  
}

# ui.R ------------------------------------------------------------

ui <-
  
  fluidPage(
    
    
    titlePanel(title = "test data"),
    fileInput("file", "Choose csv file",
              accept = c(".xlsx", ".xls", ".csv", ".txt")
    ),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabsetPanelID  == 'tab1'",
      uiOutput("ui_elements1"),
      uiOutput("sheet_elements1")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tabsetPanelID == 'tab2'",
      uiOutput("ui_elements2"),
      uiOutput("sheet_elements2")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabsetPanelID",
                  tabPanel("Tab1", value = "tab1",
                           plotlyOutput("plot1")
                  ) 
                  ,
                  tabPanel("Tab2", value = "tab2",
                           plotlyOutput("plot2"))
      )  
    ) 
  ) 

# server.R ------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  # ui_elementsUI------------------------------------------------------------
  
  ui_elementsUI <- function(x, y) {
    
    tagList(
      h4("Select X and Y datasets"),
      fluidRow(
        
        column(12,
               selectizeInput(inputId = x, label = "X data", choices = names( data()  ))
        )
      ),
      
      fluidRow(
        
        column(12,
               selectizeInput(inputId = y, label = "Y data", choices = names(data()), multiple = T, selected = names(data())[2])
        )
      )
      
    )
    
  }
  # sheet_elementsUI------------------------------------------------------------
  sheet_elementsUI <- function(sheet){
    
    tagList(
      
      fluidRow(
        
        column(12,
               selectInput(inputId = sheet, label = "Sheet", choices = excel_sheets(input$file$datapath))
               
        )
      )
    ) 
  }
  
  
  # Render sheet elements after file upload ------------------------------------
  
  output$sheet_elements1 <- renderUI({
    req(input$file)
    sheet_elementsUI("sheet1")
  })
  
  
  output$sheet_elements2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$file)
    sheet_elementsUI("sheet2")
  })
  
  
  # Render UI elements after file upload ------------------------------------
  
  
  output$ui_elements1 <- renderUI({
    if (has_file()) {
      
      ui_elementsUI("x1","y1")
    }
  })
  
  
  output$ui_elements2 <- renderUI({
    if (has_file()) {
      ui_elementsUI("x2","y2")
    }
  })
  
  plot_render <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(input$file != "", "Plots will display after choosing the csv file. Make sure all your csv files are in the 'data' folder in the main project tree
             ")
    )
    
    foo <-  function(x, y){
      plotly_stacked (df =  data(), x_colName = input[[x]] ,cols = c(input[[x]], input[[y]] ))
    }
    
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    
    plot_render()("x1", "y1")
    
  })
  output$plot2<- renderPlotly({
    
    plot_render()("x2", "y2")
  })
  
  # Reactive expression to read in uploaded file ----------------------------
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    foo <- function(sheet){
      
      df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, sheet = input[[sheet]])
      
      return(df)
      
    }
    if(  input$tabsetPanelID  == 'tab1'){
      result <- foo("sheet1")
    } else{
      result <- foo("sheet2")
      
    }
    
    return(result)
    
  })
  
  
  # Reactive expression to check if a file has been uploaded ----------------
  
  
  has_file <- reactive({
    !is.null(input$file) && !is.na(input$file$name)
  })
  
}

shinyApp( ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `data <- reactive(...)` with the following code, and use `data1()` and `data2()` for `tab1` and `tab2`, respectively.

```
foo <- function(sheet){
  df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, sheet = input[[sheet]])
  return(df)
}

data1 <- reactive({
  req(input$file)
  foo("sheet1")
})

data2 <- reactive({
  req(input$file)
  foo("sheet2")
})
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work! In case I have to create 7 different tabs, each tab should have its own, x, y, data and sheet IDs right? Is there an easier way to generate this , like in a loop? else the code will become too cumbersome. I want the number of tabs = no of excel sheets. In this case, I manually created 2 tabs

Comment: At the end , I want all these ids to be generated dynamically, based on the no of  excel sheets. I am not sure if I am using the right approach in this code

Comment: Determine the number of sheets you have and use `lapply` to loop through all the sheets.